“From Recipient(s)” Outlook Rules Not Running/Working
I have rules that sends specific groups of recipients to specific folders. The way the rule is set up is when an email comes from specific recipients. It will go directly to that folder and stop processing rules.
Recently has been issues were certain recipients across rules have not been automatically rerouted to the correct folder and stays in the inbox.
I’m not sure why it is doing it at this point. I’m using Outlook 365 and I attempted to create the same outlook rules on the web version of Outlook to see if it was an issue with local laptop network. My thought process was that if the look on the web version has the rules on the server then it would automatically apply with my outlook 365 app or laptop was running. Also thinking that if it has to do with the size of my rule, then running it from the server would stop that issue from happening. .Unfortunately this didn’t help and im at a loss on want to do
I don’t see any topic that helps with this so any assistance will be great.
